# How can I duplicate this paint texture?

Tags: painting, patching-drywall

I patched a hole in my wall. Now I am going to paint. My walls have a slight texture to them. I think it's a pretty common type of texturing; very subtle.
How can I match this texture?
Preferably a manual way since it's a small hole (baseball size). But if I need a product that would be helpful information also.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think @EdBeal is correct in that it's orange peel texture. They make [products](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_4_12?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=orange+peel+texture+spray&sprefix=orange+peel+%2Caps%2C149&crid=23EIRFWDVJHLL&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aorange+peel+texture+spray) to recreate these textures, and you can buy them at your local box store. Some tips, having done something similar with knockdown texturing: 1) Get yourself a couple scrap pieces of drywall to experiment on first. 2) Spray from a bit of a distance (12-18"?) 3) It's messy, use a drop cloth or newspaper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could use a shaggy paint roller to get this effect.  There are a variety of rollers and covers, so you should take those pics with you to ask a store associate which roller would likely get you that result.

As @EdBeal mentions, don't use tape as it'll leave a line.  Feather out your paint to make the repair virtually disappear.  The simplest way to feather is to let your roller get dry and roll it around the edges of your wet paint to try to soak some of it back up.

And make sure you aren't filling in too much of the existing texture.  You don't want an odd looking, smooth ring around your repair.

Comment: Hmm. Are you suggesting using a roller to roll-on some spackle? It might have to be watered down a bit, but that's an interesting idea..

Comment: Actually to me, that texture looks more like the paint itself, rather than anything under the paint.  If it was texture under the paint, I think you would see less detail on the texture or places that weren't painted, due to the texture being too deep or enough of a corner that the paint roller or brush couldn't get to it.  I know wall texture is out there, and that's what it could be, but it's not something I have experience with it.

Comment: Even with a 1" nap you will not get it to match an orange peel.

Answer (score 4):

Ok this looks like orange peal it is tough to match. Unless a large area is tapered . be careful don't try to tape off and. Make a zone area I did this many years ago and after 3 tries I could still see the lines from the tape but the owner was happyI have learned to never use tape because there is always a line even with sanding.

Answer (score 0):

Tape some plastic cling film on a piece of wall that is undamaged. Mix plaster of Paris with sand and smear onto the plastic, a little bit larger than your hole and about 2cm / 1” thick. Take a wooden board and press firmly onto the plaster, compressing it into the plastic, waiting 10 minutes. When dry, remove from wall. This is your ‘casting mold’.

Smear some plaster on the repaired spot, lay clingfilm over it and press your casting mold into wet plaster. When dry remove the film and paint.